# Highcharts : how to display only days on xaxis?

Tags: highcharts

I'am using highstock to display my data.
The ticks on the xaxis have to show only days for a week range time.
The problem I'am facing in this example ([see fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/o86ngjqu/)) is that the first tick is presenting hours, I want only to show days and no hours in the xaxis, is there any way to achieve that ?
I set startOnTick attribute to true

```
xAxis: {
   startOnTick: true,
}
```

So now the chart starts with a day but the first tick still an hour value is there a way to move the first tick to the chart origin (0,0) coordinates?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not enough to set the format for milliseconds. In API we can read:

> For a datetime axis, the scale will automatically adjust to the
> appropriate unit. This member gives the default string representations
> used for each unit. For intermediate values, different units may be
> used, for example the day unit can be used on midnight and hour unit
> be used for intermediate values on the same axis.

You need to define `dateTimeLabelFormats` for more units or use `formatter` function for labels.

```
xAxis: {
  ...,
  dateTimeLabelFormats: {
    millisecond: '%b %e',
    second: '%b %e',
    minute: '%b %e',
    hour: '%b %e',
    day: '%b %e',
    week: '%b %e',
    month: '%b %e',
    year: '%b %e'
  }
}
```

---

**Live demo:** https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/5r1v8tLo/

**API Reference:**

https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/xAxis.dateTimeLabelFormats

https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/xAxis.labels.formatter

Comment: thanks .. I also tried  dateTimeLabelFormats but once you expand the chart size : see https://jsfiddle.net/4yzw2Ln0/ (same fiddle you provided but the the chart size changed) some ticks will be duplicated.

Comment: You are right, but that is a normal behaviour. To get rid of the duplicates set `minTickInterval` to one day. Example: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/gdchoqwx/

Comment: oh great I used tickInterval and set it to one day : 24 * 3600 * 1000  but it didndt work,  minTickInterval  works ! thanks you